# React Native FlatList not scrolling within flexbox UI

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I have spent hours trying to understand why my flat list refuses to scroll. I have see many solutions about adding "flexGrow: 1" to the contentContainerStyle prop of the list, sadly that doesnt solve for me here. I have tried many variations of using flex/flexGrow: 1 in the style prop too, but still no scrolling. I attach what my code for this page looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dimensions, FlatList, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Button, Block, Text } from "galio-framework";
import Theme from "../../constants/Theme";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
import SvgCarIcon from "../../components/SvgCarIcon";
import DashIcons from "../../components/DashIcons";

export default class MakePayment extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            source: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0,
                latitudeDelta: 0.005,
                longitudeDelta: 0.005
            },
            rideOptions: [
                {
                    title: "Ride A",
                    passengers: 4,
                    arrivalTime: "10:00 - 10:07 arrival",
                    price: "5.00",
                    isSelected: false
                },
                {
                    title: "Ride B",
                    passengers: 7,
                    arrivalTime: "10:00 - 10:07 arrival",
                    price: "7.50",
                    isSelected: false
                },
                {
                    title: "Ride C",
                    passengers: 6,
                    arrivalTime: "12:00 - 13:30 arrival",
                    price: "3.50",
                    isSelected: false
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    toggleOption = (INDEX) => {
        let updatedRideOptions = this.state.rideOptions.slice().map((item, index) => {
            INDEX === index ? item["isSelected"] = !item["isSelected"] : item["isSelected"] = false
            return item;
        })
        this.setState({rideOptions: updatedRideOptions}, () => console.log(this.state.rideOptions));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let { lat, lng } = this.props.route.params.source.geometry.location;
        this.setState({
            source: {
                ...this.state.source,
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: lng
            }
        }, () => console.log(this.state.source));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar hidden/>
                <MapView
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    showsCompass={true}
                    showsUserLocation={true}
                    style={styles.map}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: 37.78825,
                        longitude: -122.4324,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0421
                    }}
                    region={this.state.source}
                />
                <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.header}>Time To Pick A Dash!</Text>
                    <FlatList
                        contentContainerStyle={{
                            width: "90%",
                            flexGrow: 1,
                            alignItems: "center",
                            borderColor: "red",
                            borderStyle: "solid",
                            borderWidth: 2
                        }}
                        scrollEnabled={true}
                        keyExtractor={((item, index) => String(index))}
                        data={this.state.rideOptions}
                        renderItem={({ item , index}) => {
                            return (
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    activeOpacity={0.9}
                                    style={[styles.dashRideBox, item.isSelected && styles.btnSelected]}
                                    onPress={() => this.toggleOption(index)}
                                >
                                    <SvgCarIcon color={item.isSelected ? Theme.COLOURS.WHITE : Theme.COLOURS.SECONDARY}/>
                                    <Block style={{ paddingRight: 25 }}>
                                        <Text size={18} color={item.isSelected ? Theme.COLOURS.WHITE : Theme.COLOURS.SECONDARY}>{item.title}&nbsp;
                                            <Text small style={item.isSelected && styles.textSelected}>{item.passengers}</Text>
                                        </Text>
                                        <Text size={14} style={item.isSelected ? styles.textSelected : styles.subText}>{item.arrivalTime}</Text>
                                    </Block>
                                    <Text color={item.isSelected ? Theme.COLOURS.WHITE : Theme.COLOURS.SECONDARY} size={24}>{item.price}</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            );
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
                <Block style={styles.paymentContainer}>
                    <Block style={{
                        flex: 0.4, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center"
                    }}>
                        <Block style={styles.card}>
                            <DashIcons name={"visa"} size={40}/>
                            <Text size={14} color={Theme.COLOURS.SUB_TEXT} bold>VISA ***** 4700</Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={{
                                    flex: 1,
                                    alignItems: "center"
                                }}
                                onPress={() => console.log("Card drop down opened...")}
                            >
                                <DashIcons name={"dropdown-arrow"} size={14} color={"grey"}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </Block>
                        <Button style={styles.recent}>
                            <DashIcons name={"clock"} size={22}/>
                        </Button>
                    </Block>
                    <Button style={styles.confirmBtn} color={"#F2F2F2"}>
                        <Text size={24} color={Theme.COLOURS.SECONDARY}>Confirm your dash</Text>
                    </Button>
                </Block>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const { width: WIDTH } = Dimensions.get("window"); //Max Width of phone screen
const { height: HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get("window");

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
        backgroundColor: Theme.COLOURS.WHITE
    },
    menuContainer: {
        flex: 0.3,
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center",
        width: "100%",
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        elevation: 1
    },
    dashRideBox: {
        flexGrow: 0.475,
        backgroundColor: Theme.COLOURS.WHITE,
        width: "100%",
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 10,
        elevation: 3,
        shadowRadius: 10
    },
    map: {
        flex: 0.45,
        width: WIDTH
    },
    paymentContainer: {
        marginTop: 10,
        flex: 0.25,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderStyle: "solid",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
    },
    header: {
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Theme.COLOURS.SUB_HEADER,
        paddingVertical: 10
    },
    subText: {
        color: Theme.COLOURS.SUB_TEXT
    },
    card: {
        flex: 0.7,
        height: 45,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: Theme.COLOURS.WHITE,
        elevation: 5,
        paddingLeft: 10
    },
    recent: {
        flex: 0.3,
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: Theme.COLOURS.WHITE,
        elevation: 5,
    },
    confirmBtn: {
        flex: 0.6,
        width: 343,
        borderRadius: 30,
        elevation: 3
    },
    btnSelected: {
        backgroundColor: Theme.COLOURS.BUTTON
    },
    textSelected: {
        color: Theme.COLOURS.WHITE
    }
})
```

**Any advice as to why the list doesn't scroll?**

Link to expo snack to see current state: *[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@chipzstar/dashrides-snack)*

Comment: Hey , Share your code on [snack](https://snack.expo.io)

Comment: Hey @OliverD, I can share my code on snack with all the assets, but it wont run cos of the 3rd party dependencies/packages. ;/

Comment: Ok I made the snack. 
https://snack.expo.io/@chipzstar/dashrides-snack

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm in mobile now, I just checked it, try to delete width and alignItems in content container style for flatlist, I don't know why added it but when I delete it it's work https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/648d74

Comment: Hi @OliverD. I just tried your solution (removing width and alignItems center), and it works just how i wanted. The issue was definitely the the "alignItem" property though. Not sure why I included it. Thank you very much!! :)